# where i should create wavesurfer instance in VUE?

Tags: vue.js, wavesurfer.js

i want to display a wav file in Vue with wavesurfer.js, my code :

```
     var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
          container: '#waveform',
          waveColor: 'red',
          progressColor: 'purple'
        });

     wavesurfer.load('https://ia902606.us.archive.org/35/items/shortpoetry_047_librivox/song_cjrg_teasdale_64kb.mp3');

     new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          data: {
            message: 'data1'
          },
        })
```

but i get error:

```
Unknown custom element: <wave> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i find a solution!

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-use-wavesurfer-with-vuejs-solved/14924

just write like this:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  },
  mounted () {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
          container: '#waveform',
          waveColor: 'blue',
          progressColor: 'purple'
      })
      this.wavesurfer.load('https://ia902606.us.archive.org/35/items/shortpoetry_047_librivox/song_cjrg_teasdale_64kb.mp3')
    })
  },
  methods: {
    play () {
        this.wavesurfer.playPause()
    }
  }
})
```